# kubuntu 15.04 wifi problem (lenovo T420)

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, lenovo, intel-wireless

I have a Lenovo T420 laptop, I have recently upgraded from kubuntu 14.4 to kubuntu 15.04 and since then I have problems with wireless connections, when trying to connect to a wireless network that I have already connected to in the past the process cannot get past 'Waiting for authorization' step, to resolve that I must go into the 'Connection editor' delete the wireless network and then when I try to connect to the network it prompts me for password and after entering the password I can connect until the next time I restart my laptop or revive it from sleep and it goes back to the 'Waiting for authorization' problem when trying to connect to the network.

```
yair@yair-ThinkPad-T420:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:21ce]
        Kernel driver in use: e1000e
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 AGN [8086:1311]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: still need help if anyone knows the fix, it seems like it might have something to do with CA for wireless networks but im not sure

Answer (score 1):

I had the same symptoms with wireless connection after upgrading a desktop computer to Kubuntu 15.04.  After lots of research I found something that suggested that combined WPA/WPA2 mode on the router that generated the wireless access point could be problematic.  I reset the parameters in the router to force it use WPA.  As suggested, I used AES (NOT TKIP).  I did this several days ago and have had no problem since.

Today's updates included an update to the DHCP client and I have not investigated to see whether this could correct the original problem.

Comment: This not possible as the network im connecting to is the university network and i have no control on ssid broadcast or password

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after installing kubuntu 15.04 on x230. I changed the dns server addresses which fixed it.

I don't know why that is, perhaps some setting is not properly initialized unless the dns servers are changed.

How you do it:

- Select wifi connection from the panel
- Click the tiny "settings" icon on the right above the wifi list
- Select your wifi connection and select "edit"
- Click the "ipv4" tab
- For "method" Select "Automatic (only adresses)"
- Enter into "DNS servers" field a comma separated list of ip addresses to working dns servers.

For example google's dns servers are.

```
8.8.8.8
```

and

```
8.8.4.4
```

So you would enter "8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4"

Hope this helps in your situation too.

Comment: Nice try but no, I can't even 'edit' connection. when i click on edit all i can edit is the connection name and even defining a new connection and applying your suggestion do not solve it

Answer (score 0):

<strike>None of the above works for me, but a workaround is to change the router to not to ask for a password and hide the SSID. This raises some security concerns so this is only for the brave...</strike>

**Update :**
In my case the problem was that kwalletmanager stopped working so I had to re install it. You should check the following :

1. execute `sudo apt-get install kwalletmanager`
2. Double check that in `~/.kde/share/config/kwalletrc` you have everything enabled like this :
   [Wallet]
   Default Wallet=kdewallet
   Enabled=true
3. Open connection editor delete your old wifi entries
4. Restart machine
5. Reconnect to wifi

Comment: This not possible as the network im connecting to is the university network and i have no control on ssid broadcast or password

Answer (score 0):

I have just a workaround for this problem

```
nmcli device wifi connect "YOUR-NETWORK-NAME" password "PASSWORD"
```

with this connection is working and could be reconected via network manager but only connection to "YOUR-NETWORK-NAME".

It will crate new connection in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections with password inside of it. Looks like an issue is that for some reason NM can't get password from wallet-manager.